# Android touch event on home screen not on any view

Tags: android, touch, broadcast

I am working on a Android Application project in which I am doing continuous task and when user click anywhere on home screen of phone I have to stop this work. Please anyone guide me how I can get touch event in my app so I can do some task. Any Broadcast for touch or any thing I can use. So that I can get in my application. Guide me.

I Do not want this thing 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

try this in your activity class,

```
     public class TouchActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            Log.d("Touch", "Touch");
            sendBroadcast(new Intent("touch_event_has_occured"));
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

now in your global broadcast receiver you will get the brodcast

```
public class TouchReveiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("touch_event_has_occured"))
        {
            Log.d("Touch", "Touch");
        }
    }

}
```

don't forget to register the receiver with the action

Comment: This only works when application is open . I want to get touch event even application is not open .